# JDBC - Using sysdate in prepared statement produces an error

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

i get the following error when I execute the prepared statement. I use ms-access for my database

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 10.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3148)
.....
```

Here is my prepared statement

```
addUserSt = con.prepareStatement("insert into Accounts(Username, First_name, last_name, gender, birthday, email, civil_status, password, role, date_join) values(?,?,?,?,CDATE(?),?,?,?,?, sysdate)");
```

and here's how i execute that prepared statement... the variables here are all strings

```
                dc.addUserSt.setString(1, uname);
                dc.addUserSt.setString(2, fname);
                dc.addUserSt.setString(3, lname);
                dc.addUserSt.setString(4, gender);
                dc.addUserSt.setString(5, bday);
                dc.addUserSt.setString(6, email);
                dc.addUserSt.setString(7, civil);
                dc.addUserSt.setString(8, pass);
                dc.addUserSt.setString(9, role);
```

I can't understand why I get that too few parameters error, i think that i setString well the prepared statement. when I remove the sysdate and remove also the date_join in the columns, the program runs perfectly. But i need to get the current date to store in the database. 
Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sysdate is not valid function. Use Date() instead.

And don't forget the parenthesis when using functions.